# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'replace'

Tags: javascript

I'm studying javascript. I just want to understand why the strip2() function in the below code doesn't work, and returns an error.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function strip1(str) {
  return str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "")
};
function strip2() {
  return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "")
};

var text = ' Hello  ';
console.log(strip1(text));  // Hello
console.log(strip2(text));  // Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'replace'
</script>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

`this` in that context is a pointer to the global `window` object, which doesn't have a replace function (since it isn't a string). So as a result, it throws an error.

Answer (score 2):

The correct version would be:

```
console.log(strip2.call(text));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function strip2() {
  return arguments[0].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "")
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript this always refers to the “owner” of the function we're executing, or rather, to the object that a function is a method of.

So strip2 is calling replace on the global `window` object.

For reference, this is an article explaining the `this` keyword in JavaScript: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html